# Updating ActiveRecord with text from a joined table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, active-record, join

I have an Active Record update with the following data model:

- `TvMenuProfile` has one `rich_text_special`
- `Bar` has zero to many `tv_menu_profiles`
- `Special` has one `bar_id` and one `description`

I want to copy all of the `Special.description` columns to each `TvMenuProfile`. The link between the two is `tv_menu_profile.bar.specials.first.description`.

To my understanding this cannot be accomplished with a single Arel query, but could possibly be done with a complex, raw SQL query.

The following is what I have right now, which works. However it performs an `UPDATE` for each `TvMenuProfile` that has a bar that has a special, which is not ideal.

```
TvMenuProfile.joins(bar: :specials).select("*").each do |profile|
  plain_text_description = profile.bar.specials.first.description
  profile.update_attribute(:rich_text_special, plain_text_description)
end
```

Any thoughts on improving this?